# Gack Error Id : 2020409769-104966 (551437190) when there is no constructor without parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components, controller, gack, constructor, imperativeapex

When a Lightning Action is called from LWC and a DTO model instance is passed, where the corresponding DTO Model class doesn't have no arguments constructor, an internal error is shown:

> Gack Error Id : 2020409769-104966 (551437190)

The listing of the LWC component

```
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Pass DTO2" onclick={pass2}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

The listing of the Javascript part of the LWC

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import passDTO2 from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.passDTO2'
export default class Component extends LightningElement {
    reduceErrors(errors) {
        if (!Array.isArray(errors)) {
            errors = [errors];
        }
        let err = errors[0];
        if (err.messages  && Array.isArray(err.messages)) {
            errors = errors.concat(err.messages);
        }
        if (err.body && Array.isArray(err.body.pageErrors)) {
            errors = errors.concat(err.body.pageErrors);
        }
        if (err.body && Array.isArray(err.body.duplicateResults)) {
            errors = errors.concat(err.body.duplicateResults);
        }
        if (err.body && err.body.fieldErrors) {
            for (const x in err.body.fieldErrors ) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(err.body.fieldErrors, x)) {
                    errors = errors.concat(err.body.fieldErrors[x]);
                }
            }
        }
    
        return (
            errors
                // Remove null/undefined items
                .filter((error) => !!error)
                // Extract an error message
                .map((error) => {
                    // UI API read errors
                    if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
                        return error.body.map((e) => e.message);
                    }
                    // UI API DML, Apex and network errors
                    else if (error.body && typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
                        return error.body.message;
                    }
                    else if (typeof error.problem === 'string') {
                        return error.problem;
                    }
                    // JS errors
                    else if (typeof error.message === 'string') {
                        return error.message;
                    }
                    
                    // Unknown error shape so try HTTP status text
                    return error.statusText;
                })
                // Flatten
                .reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr), [])
                // Remove empty strings
                .filter((message) => !!message)
        );
    }

    pass2() {
        passDTO2({data: {}})
        .then(() => {
            alert('success');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(this.reduceErrors(error).join('. '));
        })
    }
}
```

The model class

```
@namespaceAccessible
public with sharing class DTO2 {
    public String x;
    public DTO2(string x) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ x ' + x);
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

The controller class

```
public with sharing class Controller {

 
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void passDTO2(DTO2 data){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ data: ' + data);
        throw new UnexpectedException('Internal exception here');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially noticed that issue on `December 19, 2022` when trying to find a workaround for another gack id.

Initial gack id was actually `An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1401126796-122884 (1052930401)`

I have reported this to Salesforce support, but it took three months for them to acknowledge this issue.

Finally they have acknowledged this issue.

> March 9, 2023 at 9:54 AM
>
> Our higher support team has raised a bug for the issue. The issue was
> because of the default constructor check was not added from our end
> for the Apex.

SF opened a known issue about this case:
[https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000sliyUAAQ/~](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000sliyUAAQ/%7E)

Comment: Issue leads to a 404

Comment: @TemporaryFix try again?